# How to mock sealed classes with mockk?

Tags: android, kotlin, mocking, mockk

I am trying to mock a sealed class which looks something like this:

```
sealed class Location

class Home: Location{
    val name = "Home"
}
```

I would like to be able to do the following:

```
val mockHome = mockk<Home>() {
    every { name } answers { "My Home" }
}
```

But unfortunately when I run this it fails with the following error:

> io.mockk.MockKException: Missing calls inside every { ... } block.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yup, you cannot. A sealed class is intended to have a closed set of implementations. It is vital for logic such as the 'when' expression to work. It is like trying to mock an enum. Is there a good reason for it to be mocked and not just use a real instance?

Comment: I think the reason may be simpler. The property just became a field because of compiler optimization. Have you tried a regular function?

Answer (score 1):

For now you cannot. but this issue was fixed in this [PR](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/pull/988/commits) and we are waiting for next release of Mockk. you can track this PR for more information