# How to mock sealed classes and test their arguments with Mockk?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, viewmodel, model-view-intent

I am trying to test sealed classes in a view model:

```
sealed class MyActions {

data class BottomNavigate(val fragment: Fragment2) :
    MyActions()
}
```

How do I test BottomNavigate was called with an argument of type Fragment2 using mockk or anything else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55654822/how-to-mock-sealed-classes-with-mockk
It seems you can't do that :(

Comment: Yes, it is similar, I had looked at that question, and I also need to capture some arguments passed to the sealed class.